# How to get colormap from image to save it as colorimage with imwrite()

Tags: matlab, image-processing, png

I have a matrix holding a picture which is in colors using image()

```
load image_matrix.mat;
image(image_matrix);
imsave(image_matrix, 'test.png', 'png', 'Compression', 'none');
```

This code results in a greyscale image. 
Somehow I should use the colormap to save the image. But where to get it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the image is grayscale, `imgage()` just puts another colormap on it. Try

```
cm=parula; % or a different colormap
imsave(image_matrix,cm, 'test.png', 'png', 'Compression', 'none');
```

Make sure that `image_matrix` is double in range [0-1] or uint8 [0-255]